# Can't create symmetric keys when adding IoT device

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I try to add an IoT device in the Azure portal. When I let the portal create the symmetric keys it works fine, when I paste in our own symmetric keys it errors out. Our keys look like this:

ODY2OTE0MDI0NDExNzEw (base64, 20 bytes)

An error prevented the device from being created. {"message":"BadRequest:{\r\n  \"Message\": \"ErrorCode:ArgumentInvalid;BadRequest\",\r\n  \"ExceptionMessage\": \"Tracking ID:d6de10axxxxxxxxxb51a595aa8f72082-G:15-TimeStamp:04/23/2019 20:24:48\"\r\n}"}

Comment: It is important to notice that the key base has to be 16bytes or larger. I used IMEI numbers that had only 15 bytes (the resulting key was 20+). After adding a prefix it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your symmetric keys must have a key length between 16 bytes and 64 bytes in the valid Base64 format.

example for 16bytes:

**1234567890123456**

**MTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Ng==**

I do recommend to use a *SHA256CryptoServiceProvider.ComputeHash* of the secret string for your device symmetric keys, for example:

secret string: **hello**

primary key: **LPJNul+wow4m6DsqxbninhsWHlwfp0JecwQzYpOLmCQ=**